# How does this closure make componentDidUpdate behave like useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading Dan Abramov's article: [A Complete Guide to useEffect](https://iqkui.com/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything), and in the section: Each Render Has Its Own… Everything, there are two examples, first
uses `useEffect` like this:

```
const UseEffectCounter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`You clicked ${count} times`);
        }, 3000);
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+1</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The above example logs sequentially after the 3 seconds timeout.

The second example uses `componentDidUpdate` like this:

```
class ComponentDidUpdateCounter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`You clicked ${this.state.count} times`);
        }, 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})}>+1</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If click n times and wait for the timeout finishes, console logs `You clicked n times` for n times, rather than the sequential number of clicks. This is fine because React mutates `this.state.count` to always point to the latest value of the state.

However, simply modifying the `componentDidUpdate` like this would make the component behave like the first example:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const count = this.state.count
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`You clicked ${count} times`);
    }, 3000);
}
```

How does this closure make the component behave like `useEffect`?

Comment: @BrianThompson can you provide an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference is that `this.state.count` is evaluated at different points in your examples.

`this.state.count` is evaluated in the third example after each update at the when you assign it to `count`, whereas in the second example `this.state.count` is evaluated at the **end** of the timeout. At the end of the timeout, all of the updates have most likely already occurred, so you see the same values logged. But assigning it to a local `count` variable only defers the logging, not the evaluation.

In the `useEffect` version, each render is creating a new count const, and a const can only be assigned once. This is why it logs each value sequentially, because a const can never be updated, even if you wait on a state update to complete.